# Enlarge and restrict a quadrilateral polygon in opencv 2.3 with C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I can't find this answer anywhere, I hope somebody could help me.

I have an image (all black) with a white generic quadrilateral polygon inside it, and the correspondent 4 corners coordinates of such polygon.

I need to find the corners of a slightly enlarged quadrilateral and the same for a slightly reduced one (the shape must be the same, just a resize of the quadrilateral inside the image).

Is there a function which allows me to do that, or should I compute manually some geometry?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a vertex p of the polygon, with its predecessor p1 and successor p2.

[image]

The vectors between these points are

```
v1 = p1 - p
v2 = p2 - p
```

(The computation is componentwise for the x and y coordinates respectively).
In the shrunk polygon the vertex p is moved to p' along the line 
which halves the angle a between the vectors v1 and v2.
The vector w in this direction is

```
w = v1 + v2
```

and the unit vector v in this direction is

```
v = w / |w| = (w_x, w_y) / sqrt(w_x*w_x + w_y*w_y)
```

The new point p' is

```
p' = p + k * v ,  i.e. :
p_x' = p_x + k * v_x
p_y' = p_y + k * v_y
```

where k is the shifting distance (a scalar).

If the vertex p is convex (as in the figure), then k >= 0 means 
shrinking and k <= 0 means expanding. 
If the vertex p is concave, then k >= 0 means 
expanding and k <= 0 means shrinking.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked, and also in a very compact way.

Comment: Doesn't handle the case when one of the edges of quad is really small. So an inside offest is actually a triangle. With this method you will get a figure 8

Answer (score 0):

What you want is polygon offset. If you want to use an existing library. Consider using [Clipper](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper/documentation/Docs/Units/ClipperLib/Functions/OffsetPolygons.htm)

```
     void OffsetPolygons(const Polygons &in_polys, 
         Polygons &out_polys, 
         double delta, 
         JoinType jointype = jtSquare, double MiterLimit = 2.0);
```

**This function offsets the 'polys' polygons parameter by the 'delta' amount. Positive delta values expand outer polygons and contract inner 'hole' polygons. Negative deltas do the reverse.**

Although I must add for a simple geometry like a Quadrilateral it is easy to do it from scratch.

- Identity all four infinite lines that form the Quadrilateral
- Offset the lines parallel to themselves
- Compute intersection of these new lines

Just be careful of corner cases. When you offset a quadrilateral which has one very small edge. It will become a triangle on offset.

Comment: Thank you, but I'd rather use only opencv, no external libraries.
And also the geometric implementation you said wouldn't work in all cases: for example, when the quadrilateral has an almost vertical side, which means a very high (or low) slop and so an extremely high (or low) intercept of the y-axis, computing a slight change in such intercept wouldn't affect so much the parallel line. So I should use dynamic offsets in that case.

I used the vector implementation explained by Jiri. It worked.

Comment: Jiri's case doesn't handle the corner case i mention in my answer. I am not sure I understand the case you mention.

Comment: Yes, but in my case I don't have to handle with small edges. Your solution using Clipper library would be perfect, but I should only use opencv library.

Handling with all the parallel lines and then compute the intersections was a little bit long, while the vector implementation took me just 10 lines of C++ code.

But thank you anyway for your help.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with the answer of [parapura rajkumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/764882/parapura-rajkumar). I wanted to add that the solution of [Jiri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/805681/jiri) is not 100% correct because the vertex centroid of a quadrilateral is different to the area centroid of a quadrilateral, as it is written [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateral#Remarkable_points_and_lines_in_a_convex_quadrilateral). For the enlargement one would have to use the area centroid - or the much more elegant [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7995923/9827698) with the parallel lines mentioned by [parapura rajkumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/764882/parapura-rajkumar). I just want to add the following to this answer:

You can simply determine the outer points of the enlarged quadrilateral by computing the normal vectors of the vectors between the points of the original quadrilateral. Afterwards, normalize the normal vectors, multiply them with the offset and add them to the points of the original quadrilateral. Given these outer points you can now compute the intersection of the parallel lines with this [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection#Given_two_points_on_each_line).